# Translating LINQ query into CRM QueryExpression while using 'select new'

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, query-expressions

I've got the following container class:

```
public class AssetAndItsDepositsContainer
    {
        public jp_asset Asset { get; set; }
        public jp_deposit Deposit { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to take the following LINQ query:

```
from a in serviceContext.jp_assetSet
join d in serviceContext.jp_depositsSet on a.Id equals d.jp_assetid.Id
where a.statecode == jp_assetState.Active &&
      a.jp_isonhold = true
select new AssetAndItsDepositsContainer()
{
     Asset = a,
     Deposit = d
})
.ToList();
```

And "translate" it by using `QueryExpression`?
This is what I came up with so far, but I don't know how to mimic the `select new` expression:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(jp_asset.EntityLogicalName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)jp_assetState.Active);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("jp_isonhold", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
LinkEntity link = query.AddLink(jp_deposit.EntityLogicalName, "Id", "jp_assetid", JoinOperator.Inner);

// Now what?
var res = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities; // gets only jp_assets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an entire `LinkEntity`, you can only access its attributes as `AliasedValue` properties on the main `Entity` itself.

I would simply retrieve the Id of the second record you're looking for as part of an `EntityReference` and then execute a [`Retrieve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx).

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Given the fact that we can access a `LinkEntity`'s attributes, we are perfectly able to construct `Entity` objects from the result set. Simply using the LINQ expression's `Select` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually construct valid `Entity` objects from linked entities. The only requirement is that the primary key of the linked entity must be available in the result set.

So, your code snippet could be extended like this:

```
var query = new QueryExpression(jp_asset.EntityLogicalName);
query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
query.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, (int)jp_assetState.Active);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("jp_isonhold", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);

LinkEntity link = query.AddLink(jp_deposit.EntityLogicalName, "Id", "jp_assetid", JoinOperator.Inner);
link.EntityAlias = "d";
link.Columns.AddColumns("jp_depositid", "jp_name");

IEnumerable<Entity> deposits = Service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities
    .Select(e => new Entity("jp_deposit")
    {
        Id = (Guid)e.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("d.jp_depositid").Value,
        ["jp_name"] = e.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("d.jp_name")?.Value
    });
```

> *Note*
>
> The example above will only work reliable for inner joins. In the result set the primary key (ID) for the linked entity will always be available. Therefore it is safe to get its value using the `.Value` syntax. All other attribute values can be retrieved using `?.Value`.
>
> For left joins you would need to filter the result set first before performing the `Select`.